# Should someone focus on having as less memory leaks as possible or having the fastest computing time?

Tags: memory, memory-leaks, standards, cpu

I was wondering:
When programming, should one focus on having as less memory leaks as possible or more on the CPU computing time?
What are the pros/cons?

Thanks!

Comment: If you ever find yourself in a situation where you are deciding whether or not to deliberately leak memory to improve runtime, you've most likely lost sight of what's actually consuming all your runtime.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch this question is a _very_ poor fit for Programmers - it would be quickly voted down and closed over there, see [What is the problem with “Pros and Cons”?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6758/31260) Recommended reading: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a program runs very quickly (e.g. a small fraction of second) and you want to run it zillion times, memory leaks do not matter at all (because in a very short time it will allocate only a small reasonable amount of memory, and the OS will reclaim the memory used by a process when that process terminates).

If your program does not run quickly (in particular if it runs continuously, e.g. because it is a server or a daemon), memory leaks are of paramount importance.

BTW, memory leaks may mean slightly different things (not the same in C as in Ocaml).

If coding in C or C++, use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to detect memory leaks.

Read also about [garbage collection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29) (see also the [GC handbook](http://gchandbook.org/)). At the very least, the terminology and the algorithms related to GC should concern you. In C, you might  sometimes consider using [Boehm's conservative garbage collector](http://www.hboehm.info/gc/).

Answer (score 1):

@basile's answers is correct. And it's worth clarifying what you mean by "memory leaks".

The strict definition of a memory leak is when a block of dynamic memory is never deallocated after being used. I would argue that this is never acceptable under any circumstances.
But, fortunately, avoiding memory leaks and using CPU time efficiently are not usually competing ideals.

It sounds like your question is more along the lines of "is it more important to cut down on CPU cycles, or is it more important to use as little memory as possible?" This is a common and completely valid question because there are many instances in programming where you can shave CPU cycles by dumping stuff into memory, or on the other hand, you can save memory by brute-forcing something.

Alas, there's no clear-cut answer. There are times when one is appropriate, and times when it goes the other way. As you grow as a programmer, you learn best practices for being efficient with both. And, in the real world, as long as you program responsibly, you will probably never see an actual situation where you *have to* sacrifice one or the other. Especially with the speed of modern chips.

Comment: In language with a GC like Ocaml, blocks are never deallocated (except by the GC itself).